# TypeScript: Can I mix using "import * from" and "require(*)"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is it ok in TypeScript to mix these too 'include' types?

```
import { SomeType, someFunc } from "./MyThings";
```

And:

```
import events = require('events');
```

The first would be a TypeScript module with an export or two... and the second is just a node module called events (I guess this could be anything pulled in from NPM too).

Am I ok to mix these two conventions in a single TypeScript file?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @Bergi - Can you explain why please?

Comment: It's potentially confusing. It will work, as it ultimately compiles to the same, but you should aim at consistency and use only one style per project (or at least, per file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is acceptable in TypeScript.

When using the `import foo = require('foo');`, you must have a module `'foo'` declared with `declare module 'foo'`, typically in a `.d.ts` file.

This is typically covered in `node.d.ts`.

Comment: Can I use import foo = require('foo'); if foo is a TypeScript file (foo.ts) with a "export default class Foo" in it?

Comment: No I don't think you can in that case.

Comment: How would I include that module inside another file if I can't use import foo = require('foo'); Whats the correct syntax?

Comment: You can `require` it with `const foo = require('foo');` (or other declaration)